# How to get desired output from apache access log in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want the count of error code and corresponding URLs from the apache access log through Bash script. The output should be like that:

```
Count   Error-code  URLs
24       404        /public_html/images/top-bottom.gif
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is entirely without testing right now:

```
gawk '1{ print $9, $7;}' httpd.log \
| sort \
| uniq -c
```

will take the fields 9 (status code) and 7 (path) from the log file, sort them (first by status code, then by path), then combine consecutive lines to one, prefixing with the number of occurences. That should get you as far as

```
21 200 /path/does/exist.html
17 404 /path/doesnt/exist.html
...
```